# Is a categorised suggestion box a good idea?

Tags: website-design, search-suggestion

We will implement a similar search box like the one live here: http://www.hepsiburada.com/

When you start typing, the suggestion box opens and it suggests you some results on the right, and some popular categories on the left.

As we cannot find a similar ready-to-use component, we decided to build it ourselves. But is it worth it? Do people find it useful?

Comment: Do you have more information about your particular problem? What are your competitors doing? If you can add more context you'll get more specific answers...

Answer (score 1):

This implementation of "*When you start typing, the suggestion box opens and it suggests you some results on the right, and some popular categories on the left.*" is really a good one.

I would give a simple suggestion of making the search bar static on the header even when the user is scrolling down. [Much like this implementation](https://searchengineland.com/google-testing-fixed-top-search-bar-85990) or this one [here](https://codepen.io/brandyscarney/pen/gbZrNQ).

PS: I believe search is really important on any website and should be more connected to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using such a feature if your resources allow it. The big advantage of that search box is that it eliminates the extra step of clicking again on which shopping category you want to look in. A common use is also to add the suggested category inline with what the user is searching for instead of opening a new box.

One potential problem with that type of search box is that it may make use of a lot of real estate on the user's screen and remember that nowadays there are more people doing e-commerce on their phones and tablets than they do on a computer screen.

All the best!